# Allow touch on table cell to cancel other current touches

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, touch

Is there a way to tell the system to cancel all touch event sequences that are currently happening in your app?

In one part of my app, I show a new view when a user selects a particular table cell.  But, I want to make sure they aren't simultaneously touching any other buttons.  For example, if they are holding a toolbar button while they select the table cell, I want to cancel that touch on the toolbar button.

A `UIActionSheet` will do this type of touch-cancelling when it is shown, and that's exactly what I want to do.

I tried setting `exclusiveTouch` on the `UIToolbar`, but that didn't seem to help.  And, the toolbar button is a `UIBarButtonItem`, so it doesn't have an `exclusiveTouch` property itself.  Is there somewhere else I should set that property that might help?

Comment: I'm trying to do it myself with a custom action sheet. Not much progress yet, but the stack trace of interest is:
-[UIApplication _cancelTouches:withEvent:sendingTouchesCancelled:includingGestures:]; -[UIApplication _cancelAllTouches]; -[UIActionSheet(Private) _presentSheetStartingFromYCoordinate:]; -[UIActionSheet(Private) presentSheetInView:];

Answer (score 1):

Set `exclusiveTouch` on the views that require exclusivity; this is probably the table cell instead of the buttons.

While you can't set `exclusiveTouch` directly on `UIBarButtonItem`s, you can set it on the toolbar's subviews (ick).